# Is there a synonym of "deploy" in terms of sending military forces to a specific place?

Tags: adjectives, synonyms

The title is pretty much self-explanatory. I know you can say something like:

> The 101st infantry division was deployed to Normandy in 1944.

But I feel like there is another way to express that. How would you have said the above sentence?

Comment: Have you checked a synonym finder?

Comment: I would say "sent" - "deployed" is correct but a little formal.

Comment: I would use "deployed" (or something more specific) rather than "sent," since the 101st Airborne Division was dropped behind enemy lines in Normandy. "Sent" is technically correct but carries less detail about the engagement.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin: It seems to me that Boyan Kushiev is looking for an alternative.(It is not the Airborne - it is the infantry.)

Comment: @Greybeard I suggest Boyan Kushiev give more details for what kind of alternative he is looking for, then. **Deploy** is the most apt verb for placing military units in an operational area. If you read something like the [Army Times](https://www.armytimes.com/news/your-army/2019/04/05/soldiers-from-101st-airborne-set-to-deploy-to-ukraine/), that is the verb they use to describe deployments: "Soldiers with 2nd Brigade Combat Team, 101st Airborne Division (Air Assault) will case their colors and deploy to Ukraine within days."

Comment: I don't wish to continue this unless you move it to "Chat". The points you seem to have missed is that (i) it was the 101st **infantry**, not the "101st *Airborne*", (ii) to deploy would be commoner among the military and formal reports. Have to look at https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+army+was+sent%2Cthe+army+was+deployed&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20army%20was%20sent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20army%20was%20deployed%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20army%20was%20sent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20army%20was%20deployed%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin, *deploy* may well be 'the most apt verb' to use for this **if** one is writing for the *Army Times*, but the OP may be writing for an entirely different audience. Although it is true that this word has, over the recent decades, percolated from the military jargon into the everyday English, it may still strike some people as jargonistic.

Comment: @jsw Once more, we need Boyan Kushiev to provide more details to know what he is looking for, including in terms of audience.

Comment: @Greybeard (i) there is no "101st infantry division." There is a 101st infantry regiment, but in WWII it was attached to the 26th infantry division. There is also a 101st airborne division. Maybe Boyan was speaking of a hypothetical, which is (yet again) why we need more explanation from him. (ii) the Ngram illustrates that both are options, but not much beyond that. A basic [Google news search](https://www.google.com/search?&tbm=nws&ei=gFOsXvqEGa6l_QaitYTgDQ&q=deploy&oq=deploy) shows that *deploy* has entered sources for general audiences, and refinements for "was deployed" show the same.

Comment: The title of this question already contains what is probably the least controversial answer to it: *send(ing)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One might say:

"The 101st infantry division was dispatched to Normandy in 1944."  or

"The 101st infantry division was stationed in Normandy in 1944."   or

"The 101st infantry division was sent to Normandy in 1944."   or even

"The 101st infantry division was positioned in Normandy in 1944."

You would however, have to be careful to make the verb tenses convey the meaning you want.

Comment: @ Rattler *To station* is transitive - "The Captain stationed his men in the trenches."-> "The men were stationed in the trenches."

Comment: @Greybeard Please note what KanneE said in a comment..."*Stationed* means you're staying there (or actually occupying it...for a long, long time). " Both of us are ex-military. For people like us, to say "stationed in Iraq" for example, means you ain't leaving for a while, and that definitely was not the idea behind the Normandy invasion.

Comment: The specific word used would depend strongly upon the context.

Comment: I think "station" was the verb I was looking for.

Comment: If you are describing a large battle, *stationed* is typically used for the defenders.

Comment: @KannE, *stationed* is indeed the wrong word for the invasion of Normandy in 1944, but it is, under different circumstances, one of the possible words for describing the fact that the military forces have been sent to a particular place. The question appeared to have been what words to use for such facts in general.